# IIS 7.0 Web Deploy authentication fails after changing Windows password... help?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, deployment

I have a very basic Windows 2008 R2 Web Server running IIS 7.0.

This is just a test/practice server, so I enabled Web Deployment using Windows Authentication.

All was well and I was able to deploy easily from VS 2010 using the Administrator account credentials.

After changing the Administrator account password, I get the following error when trying to deploy from Visual Studio (using the new password, of course):

> Error  1   Web deployment task failed...
>   ...An unsupported response was received. The response header 'MSDeploy.Response' was '' but 'v1' was expected.
>   The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

If I change the Administrator password back to the original one and try to publish using it everything works fine again. So what am I missing? Am I supposed to do something in IIS after changing the password?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check your Web Deploy rules to make sure that none of them are using the same administer account.  Use the Management Service Delegation icon from IIS Manager at the server level.  Also confirm that your app pool isn't using your administrator account.

Answer (score 1):

So this was really weird...

The problem was that my new password had a % in it. I guess this has something to do with encoding the connection string?

Anyway, passwords without the percent sign work just fine and I can change them all I want!

Comment: check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9950178/461958) answer to solve passwords with %

Answer (score 1):

1. Open IIS Manager and select the corresponding website that is causing 401 error
2. Open the "Authentication" property under the "IIS" right TAB
3. Right Click the "Anonymous Authentication" item and click "Edit"
4. Select "Application Pool Identity" in popup instead of your system account
5. Click OK

[problem will be solved]